# Math problem - Confusing sentence

Tags: meaning

In a math problem it says: 
"Twice as many boys as girls remained."
I thought this meant girls = 2 x boys.
But in the solution it says boys = 2 x girls. Who is right?

[image]

Comment: You were wrong.  If you have, say, 5 girls, what would twice as many be?  That's how many boys there were.

Comment: Mathematical word problems are almost **always** intended to be confusing! That is why practicing answering sample questions before taking a test is so useful. Once you notice that most word problems fit into a large handful of patterns (usually algebraic), solving them becomes relatively easy. If English is not your first language, they must be doubly frustrating. Practice, practice, practice!

Answer (score 1):

***Twice as many/much...as*** means ***two times more...than***.

*Twice as many boys as girls remained* means *Two times (2X...) more boys than girls remained.*

Here are two example sentences from [tolearnenglish.com](https://www.tolearnenglish.com/exercises/exercise-english-2/exercise-english-107273.php)

> There are ten times as much traffic in Boston as in New Bedford.
>
> I need four times as many leaflets as what you sent me.

Comment: There ***is*** ten times as much traffic....   *tolearnenglish* got it wrong.

Comment: Your sample sentences would be more helpful if you explained what they meant or added more context to make it totally obvious.  People outside the U.S. might not know the relative sizes of Boston and New Bedford, and it is possible that the speaker of the second sentences feels they were sent too many leaflets.

Comment: Strictly speaking, "twice as many" means "two times as many".  The expression "two times more" is ambiguous (it could mean three times as many, although it rarely does in practice).